# Outer Measure of the complement of a Vitali Set in [0,1] equal to 1

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the first part of exercise 33, ch. 1 in Stein and Shakarchi (*Real Analysis*). I am running into some difficulties following the hint though. Here is the problem (note, $N$ is a Vitali set constructed in $[0,1]$):

Show that the set $[0,1]-N$ has outer measure $m_*(N^c)=1$. [Hint: argue by contradiction, and pick a measurable set such that $N^c \subset U \subset [0,1]$ and $m_*(U) \le 1-\epsilon$.

I know that both $N$ and its complement are not measurable, so neither are countable. I know that measurable subsets of non-measurable sets have measure 0. I am not sure how to proceed given the proof though. A point to note: the book does not work with the inner measure at all, and even though I have used the inner measure in a previous course, I do not think I am allowed to for this proof.

Comment: You wrote something false. Take a Vitali set in $[0,\frac12]$, union the interval $[\frac12,1]$. This set is certainly non-measurable, but it has a measurable subset of measure $\frac12$. It is true, however, that the Vitali set has inner measure zero.

Comment: One way to see that Vitali set have inner measure zero is Lemma 2 in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/72768/8271)

Answer (score 2):

Let $I=[0,1]$. If $m_*(\mathcal N^c)<1$, then $\forall\ \varepsilon>0$, $\exists\ U$ is measurable s.t. $\mathcal N^c \subset U \subset I$ and $m_*(U)<1-\varepsilon$. Then $U^c$ is measurable, $U^c \subset N$ and $m(U^c)=1-m(U)>\varepsilon>0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the key property of the Vitali set $N$ is that the sets $N \oplus q_i$, where $\oplus$ is addition mod 1 and $\mathbb{Q} = \{q_1, q_2, \dots\}$, are disjoint.  (Not sure if this is the same notation that S&S use.)

Now, consider the sets $U^c \oplus q_i$.  Show that they are disjoint measurable sets and each has the same measure as $U^c$, which is greater than $\epsilon$.  Therefore, what can you say about the measure of $V = \bigcup_i U^c \oplus q_i$?  This should give you a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** By Theorem 3.2, $m_*(I)=m_*(U)+m_*(U^c).$