# Is this weird set in the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $C= \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, and consider a set $A = \{x_c| c \in C, x_c \in [0, 1]\}$, set of representatives of cosets in $C$. In my measure theory exercise, we proved that if $\mu$ is a translation-invariant measure, and our set $A$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra, then necessarily $\mu([0, 1]) = 1$ or $\infty$.

**Question:** Is this set $A$ in the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ (and basically, can there be a translation-invariant measure on the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$)?

The Lebesgue measure feels like it should be a translation-invariant measure, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: uh, I haven't been to mse for a while and the latex syntax chagned? I wanted to write A = A = \\{x_c| c \in C, x_c \in [0, 1]\\} (i know usually it should be \{ and \}, but it didn't render when I was writing the question, but \\{ and \\} worked)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A Vitali set is non-measurable, direct proof, without using countable additivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420440/a-vitali-set-is-non-measurable-direct-proof-without-using-countable-additivity)