# If $E_1 \cup E_2$ is a disjoint union of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $m^*(E_1 \cup E_2) = m^*(E_1) +m^*(E_2)$ may not hold

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

On Stein's real analysis page 16, he says we cannot conclude that if $E_1 \cup E_2$  is a disjoint union of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $m^*(E_1 \cup E_2) = m^*(E_1) +m^*(E_2)$. Any counterexample?

Comment: Have you read about non-measurable sets yet?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Thank you. I'm going to read it.

Answer (score 1):

See exercise 33 in the book: [Outer Measure of the complement of a Vitali Set in [0,1] equal to 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/205076/290189)

Let $E_1$ be a Vitali set, $E_2 = [0,1] \setminus E_1$.  Then $m^*(E_1) > 0$ and $m^*(E_2) = 1$, so
$$m^*(E_1 \cup E_2) = 1 < m^*(E_1) + m^*(E_2).$$