# How to pick a measurable set $U$ s.t. $\mathcal N^c \subseteq U\subseteq I $ and $m_*(U)<1-\varepsilon, \forall\epsilon\gt 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4512352/1160406), there's the following line:

> If $m_*(\mathcal N^c)<1$, then $\forall\ \varepsilon>0$, $\exists\ U$ is measurable s.t. $\mathcal N^c \subset U \subset I$ and $m_*(U)<1-\varepsilon$.

(Here $m_*$ denotes **outer** measure.)

I don't see immediately why such measurable set $U$ always exists. Can someone help to give out one such construction of $U$ with arbitrarily $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

It should be $\exists\epsilon\gt 0$ instead of $\forall\epsilon\gt 0$.

This is because if such set $U$ exists for arbitrary $\epsilon\gt 0$ then:

$$
(1-\epsilon)=(1-\epsilon) + 0\gt m_*(U)+m_*(U^c)\ge m_*(U\cup U^c)=1, \forall\epsilon,
$$

which is false.

Also $\exists\epsilon\gt 0$ is reasonable since from the assumption that $m_*(\mathcal N^c)\lt 1$, we can show that there exists such measurable set $U$. From the definition of $m_*$ we have:

$$
m_*(\mathcal N^c) =\inf\left\{ \Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathscr{l}(I_n): I_n\text{ are open intervals and }\mathcal N^c\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\ I_n\right\}\lt 1.
$$

So it must be the case that there exists some $\{I_n\}$ such that $\mathcal N^c\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\ I_n$ and $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathscr{l}(I_n)\lt 1$, otherwise $m_*(\mathcal N^c)\ge1$ which is a contradiction to the assumption. Choose $U=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\ I_n\cap[0, 1]$ and $0\lt\epsilon\lt 1-\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathscr{l}(I_n)$ satisfies the desired condition.