# $E=A\cup B$ measurable $\Rightarrow$ $A,\ B$ are measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving sets are measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72729/proving-sets-are-measurable)

The problem is:

Suppose $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ is (Lebesgue) measurable with $|E|<\infty$, and
$$E=A\cup B, \hspace{1cm} A\cap B=\emptyset.$$
If 
$$|E|=|A|_e + |B|_e,$$
then $A$ and $B$ are measurable.

Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: What does $|A|_e$ mean?  I have never seen this notation before.  Does it refer to outer measure?

Comment: @JesseMadnick  $|A|_e$ is the (Lebesgue) exterior measure of $A$.

Comment: @JesseMadnick: yes, it's the notation for outer (exterior) measure used in Zygmund-Wheeden (they write $|A|$ for the measure of $A$ and $|A|_i$ for the inner measure).

Comment: Possible dupe: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72729/8271